# Выполнить функцию в Google Apps Script по нажатию кнопки на странице

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

У меня есть страничка с формой (на хостинге, а не развернутая как web приложение в GAS), данные из которой при отправке залетают в google таблицу. Хотелось бы добавить на страницу кнопку, при нажатии на которую запускалась функция очистки листа в google таблице. Сама функция очистки в GAS выглядит следующим образом:

```
function clearList() {
  var lastRow = myTable.getLastRow();
  var range = myTable.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 3);
  range.clear();
}
```

Сама функция, если запускать ее из консоли GAS, работает. Не могу понять как можно реализовать запуск этой функции по нажатию кнопки на странице.

### UPD

С GAS удалось разобраться, нужную функцию можно вызвать из doGET:

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.function == "clearList") {
    clearList();
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Успешно!!!');
  }
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Параметр не был передан');
  }
}
```

Если в браузере перейти по ссылке `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<ID>/exec?function=clearList`, то функция срабатывает и таблица очищается. Осталось разобраться как сделать это через GET запрос, чтобы при нажатии кнопки/отправке формы не происходил переход по ссылке, а отправлялся запрос с параметром `?function=clearList`

Надеюсь +/- внятно объяснил, очень мало знаний в этой теме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем удалось собрать все в кучу, возможно когда-то кому-то пригодится. Сделал форму на странице:

```
<form name="reset-google-sheet">
  <input type="submit" value="Очистить таблицу"/>
</form>
```

и добавил обработчик:

```
const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<ID>/exec?function=clearList";
document.forms['reset-google-sheet'].addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => console.log('Таблица успешно очищена'))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
})
```

в результате получил то, что хотел реализовать - при нажатии на кнопку происходит GET запрос, вызывающий функцию на стороне GAS и таблица очищается

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте рисунок кнопки на лист
Назначьте ей Вашу функцию

https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/

Comment: извините, но это совсем не то, что мне необходимо. Вешать в самой таблице кнопку с обработчиком подразумевает открытие этой таблицы и нажатие на кнопку, что равносильно открытию таблицы, выделению всего текста и удалению. Мне же необходимо выполнять очистку таблицы без необходимости открытия само таблицы